# How do I iterate through storyboard elements without having to write out everything?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I have the situation where I need to change the text label based on various conditions, but I cannot figure out how to iterate through labels that are created within the Storyboard without having to write it all out such as below. In the below example, I am first checking if the array item exists, and if so, changing the label text and color. If not, I'd like just a default setting of blank text and the UIColor black. The labels were added to an XIB cell.

```
if let item1 = currentObjective.items[safe: 0] {
    cell.item1Label.text = item1.title
    cell.item1Label?.textColor = returnColor(item: item1)
} else {
    cell.item1Label.text = ""
    cell.item1Label?.textColor = UIColor.black
}

if let item2 = currentObjective.items[safe: 1] {
    cell.item2Label.text = item2.title
    cell.item2Label?.textColor = returnColor(item: item2)
} else {
    cell.item2Label.text = ""
    cell.item2Label?.textColor = UIColor.black
}

if let item3 = currentObjective.items[safe: 2] {
    cell.item3Label.text = item3.title
    cell.item3Label?.textColor = returnColor(item: item3)
} else {
    cell.item3Label.text = ""
    cell.item3Label?.textColor = UIColor.black
}
```

Edit: I have been asked to show the structure of the storyboard. Please see below. These are labels placed on a XIB file one by one via drag and drop.

[image]

These are all added to the swift file via IBOutlet:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the structure of the storyboard? How are the `itemXLabel`s related to each other and to the cell? Do they for example share a common super view?

Comment: Sweeper, thanks for the comment. I really appreciate it. I have updated the original post with the cell XIB view. Does this help clarify things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the title label is a sibling of the item labels, you can enumerate the array of all the item labels,

```
let itemLabels = [
    cell.item1Label!,
    cell.item2Label!,
    cell.item3Label!,
    cell.item4Label!,
]
for (i, label) in itemLabels.enumerated() {
    if let item = currentObjective.items[safe: i] {
        label.text = item.title
        label.textColor = returnColor(item: item)
    } else {
        label.text = ""
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also put the four labels as subviews of another view (perhaps a `UIStackView`) in the storyboard, so that the hierarchy becomes:

```
ObjectiveCell
    UIStackView
        item1Label
        item2Label
        item3Label
        item4Label
    titleLabel
```

Then, add an outlet for the stack view. This way, you can use `cell.stackView.arrangedSubviews`, instead of writing out the `itemLabels` array.

If you want to go one step further, don't use a fixed number of item labels! Add them dynamically to the stack view instead, based on `currentObjective.items`.

```
// remove all the existing items first (I'm guessing you're doing this in cellForRowAt or something like that)
cell.stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }

for item in currentObjective.items {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = item.title
    label.textColor = returnColor(item: item)
    cell.stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
}
```

Comment: Sweeper, thank you. Your last solution, the "one step further" solution, is actually the ideal solution which I had in mind from the beginning, but I did not know how to use the arrangedSubviews or the stackView properties. I have implemented the solution and the result is much better than I could have hoped.